# Visual Studio 2015 Report Designer nested data

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, reporting

I have data in MySQL, example:

```
+----+----------+--------+
| Id | grade    | defect |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | Grade #2 | dented |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | Grade #3 |        |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | Grade #4 | dented |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | Grade #5 |        |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | Grade #4 | short  |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | Grade #5 |        |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | Grade #1 | short  |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | Grade #6 |        |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | Grade #2 | broken |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | Grade #2 | long   |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | Grade #3 |        |
+----+----------+--------+
```

I'm wanting to create reports in Visual Studio report designer.  I can create some queries and make reports like the following:

```
+----------------------+
| Grade          Count |
+----------------------+
| Grade #1       1     |
+----------------------+
| Grade #2       3     |
+----------------------+
| Grade #3       2     |
+----------------------+
| Grade #4       2     |
+----------------------+
| Grade #5       2     |
+----------------------+
| Grade #6       1     |
+----------------------+
| Total          11    |
+----------------------+
|                      |
+----------------------+
| Defect         Count |
+----------------------+
| dented         2     |
+----------------------+
| short          2     |
+----------------------+
| broken         1     |
+----------------------+
| long           1     |
+----------------------+
| Total          6     |
+----------------------+
```

However, I'm wanting something more like this:

```
+-----------------------------+
| Grade                 Count |
+-----------------------------+
| Grade #1              1     |
+-----------------------------+
|     Short                   |
+-----------------------------+
| Grade #2              3     |
+-----------------------------+
|     dented                  |
+-----------------------------+
|     broken                  |
+-----------------------------+
|     long                    |
+-----------------------------+
| Grade #3              2     |
+-----------------------------+
| Grade #4              2     |
+-----------------------------+
|     dented                  |
+-----------------------------+
|     short                   |
+-----------------------------+
| Grade #5              2     |
+-----------------------------+
| Grade #6              1     |
+-----------------------------+
| Total                 11    |
+-----------------------------+
```

I'm sure this is possible, but I'm not sure how to do it.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  Again, I'm using visual studio 2015, mysql, vb.net, and the report designer.  I see mention of groups, child/parent, etc, but I can't see a way to make this work.  Thanks in advance.  Heck, right now I would be happy just to make a query in mysql and display in a table.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) can give you something which contains the information you want, albeit not in the exact format of your output:

```
SELECT grade,
       COUNT(*) AS defect_count,
       GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(defect, '')) AS defects
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY grade
```

**Output:**

```
Grade #1 | 1 | short
Grade #2 | 3 | dented, broken, long
Grade #3 | 2 |
Grade #4 | 2 | dented, short
Grade #5 | 2 |
Grade #6 | 1 |
```

Comment: Problem with concat is that is eats up east/west real estate.  That is the current problem with the app I'm rewriting.  If I get too many unique defects it won't fit on the page.  I would rather try and do north/south, then it's just another page.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, the query:

```
SELECT 
Grade,
SUM(Plated) AS Plated,
SUM(iF(Reject_Reason <> "", 1, 0)) AS Rejects,
Reject_Reason AS `Name`,
COUNT(Reject_Reason) As `Count`
 FROM
sorting.data
WHERE
job_name = @JobName
GROUP BY Grade, Reject_Reason
```

This got me close and the rest was done in report designer.  I added a child group.  I'm happy with how it came out.  See sample report, ignore the data, I just threw some stuff in there.

[Report setup, child group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFG83.png)[sample report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqoB4.png)